# arc shape text with css3 and ie8 support

Tags: jquery, css, canvas, internet-explorer-8, css-transforms

I have tried to give an arc shape to text with css3 properties and also alter js to support ie8. But this is not working.

```
this.$letters.each(function (i) {
    var $letter = $(this),
        transformation = (_self.options.radius === -1) ? 'none' : 'translateX(' + $letter.data('x') + 'px) translateY(' + $letter.data('y') + 'px) rotate(' + $letter.data('a') + 'deg)',
        transition = (animation) ? 'all ' + (animation.speed || 0) + 'ms ' + (animation.easing || 'linear') : 'none';


    filterIE = 'M11=' + $letter.data('x') + ', M21=' + $letter.data('y') + ',rotation=' + $letter.data("a") + 'deg'; // js function for supporting ie8
    //alert(filterIE);
    $letter.css({
        '-webkit-transition': transition,
        '-moz-transition': transition,
        '-o-transition': transition,
        '-ms-transition': transition,
        'transition': transition
    })
    .css({
        '-webkit-transform': transformation,
        '-moz-transform': transformation,
        '-o-transform': transformation,
        '-ms-transform': transformation,
        'transform': transformation,
        'filter': "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(" + filterIE + ")"  // js function for supporting ie8
    });

    function getIEVersion() {
        var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
        if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {

            var ua = navigator.userAgent;
            var re = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
            if (re.test(ua) != null)

                rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
        }
        return rv;
    }


    function checkVersion() {
        var ver = getIEVersion();

        if (ver != -1) {
            if (ver <= 9.0) {
                //.css("-ms-filter","progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.4488887394336025, M12=-0.388228567653781, M21=0.388228567653781, M22=1.4488887394336025, SizingMethod='auto expand')"
                //);// do something
            }
        }
    }

    checkVersion();
});
```

the text marked with bold is done the alteration to my js function. can anyone help me out here. i have made a demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SxNzb/2/)

Answer (score 1):

As the question was asked in 2013 and IE8 is rapidly on its way out, I thought I'd give the link to an amazing arc text CSS generator: http://csswarp.eleqtriq.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Your transform code for IE is wrong. It should be like this:

```
var cos = Math.cos;
var sin =Math.sin;
var deg2rad = 180 * Math.PI;
var filterIE = 'M11=' + ($letter.data('x')+cos($letter.data("a")/deg2rad)) + ',M12=' + sin($letter.data("a")/deg2rad) + ', M21=' + ($letter.data('y')-sin($letter.data("a")/deg2rad)) + ',M22=' + cos($letter.data("a")/deg2rad) + ',sizingMethod=\'auto expand\''
```

Also, IE9+ supports CSS3 transform. You just need the `-ms-` prefix.

Comment: Thanks @Licson, i have tried your code but the text is not coming in correct way in ie8 as it is in other browsers.

Comment: I think you should try using the jquery transform plugin. It is cross-browser and can help you save time and code.